# Open file in existing GUI Emacs from shell

Tags: osx, shell, zsh

I would like to set the shell EDITOR to use the existing running instance of GUI Emacs.

On macOS I can type `open -a Emacs file` to edit file that way. But how would `EDITOR` look to work that way?

What does not work:

`export EDITOR="emacs" # launches new gui emacs
export EDITOR="emacsclient" # launches terminal emacs in current shell
export EDITOR="open -a Emacs" # quits editing right away`

Comment: You'll probably want to try out running a daemon and then connecting to it. That should make it easy to pop up a window for editing. `open` is probably spawning a process and exiting, which tricks programs that run an editor that it's done already.

Comment: *"export EDITOR="emacsclient" # launches terminal emacs in current shell"* is noteworthy. That would not work at all unless there was an Emacs server already running. How/where/when are you starting that server?

Comment: And because this is about OSX: Does `M-x emacs-version` report the same thing when you run `emacs` vs when you run `emacsclient` ?

Comment: phils, thanks for the tip. indeed, i had a server running that i was not aware of (installed via homebrew). i have now changed EDITOR to emacsclient and now it behaves as i would like. I guess the GUI also runs the server within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question; I had a server running that I was not aware of.

```
brew services list
```

After stopping it with `brew services stop emacs-plus` or `brew services stop emacs`, I was able to configure the EDITOR with

```
export EDITOR="emacsclient"
```

to use the Emacs.app GUI as the server from the shell.